# Undertitle in xcode

Tags: objective-c

I just started to learn Objective c. Now i want a under title (small grey text) under the ''big'' title. i'm using the code:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Test";
```

but in the simulator i do not see a under title.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.authorList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`. It does not support details.

Use `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` instead.

-edit-

If you're using storyboards, remove all the cell init code and leave only the dequeue line. Then go to the interface builder and change the type of the cell there.